# Import error 'FailedCheck' using SOAPUI for ERP Integration Service

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, erp, oracle-fusion-apps

I have tried automated importing of AP Invoices by using the ERP Integration Service from SOAPUI, but I am getting the 'FailedCheck' error whenever I am running a request. I have filled the necessary information, such as the base64 encoding of the CSVs.

[Sample SOAP Code Request & Received Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOP7a.png)

I have also filled in my username and password in the Outgoing WS-Security Configuration, which I have provided by double-clicking the project name.

[Proof of credentials needed inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCzP7.png)

I also obtained a security certificate by obtaining the one used by the web service WSDL, then creating a keystore from it by the use of the tool 'keytool' from JDK. Then I used it as the keystore of my project.

[Proof of keystore applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQCGz.png)

Which I placed the necessary info for outgoing encryption.

[Proof of encryption using keystore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJwtp.png)

After the steps, I run the request, to which I received the 'FailedCheck' error (see first image). Image below is the log that I received when I encounter the said error.

[SoapUi log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wS30.png)

And here is the error log:

```
  Tue Nov 07 18:56:36 CST 2017:ERROR:java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
   java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity.getContent(GzipDecompressingEntity.java:63)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.CompressionSupport.decompress(CompressionSupport.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.PostResponseDataSource.<init>(PostResponseDataSource.java:51)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.MimeMessageResponse.<init>(MimeMessageResponse.java:55)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.WsdlMimeMessageResponse.<init>(WsdlMimeMessageResponse.java:57)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.wsdlRequest(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:68)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.afterAbstractHttpResponse(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:49)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.afterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:272)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have also tried running a request without using keystores, but I am getting an authentication error as a response. I am a beginner in this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have almost the same issue. have you resolved this?